# Horrizontal scroll in page's table make page width over 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm making a horizontal scroll-able `table` on my site and it making whole site `longer` as usual. (screenshot)
Is there a way to prevent this?
here is my `html` and `css`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7RCH.jpg)

```css
.wrapper {
    /*  table */
    height: 40%;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper_ div {
    /* div around table */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_">
    <table border="1" style="font-size:10pt;" class="wrapper">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>受注番号</th>
            <th>会社名</th>
            <th>受注日</th>
            <th>販売会社</th>
            <th>契約年数</th>
            <th>月額利用料</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <!-- SOME PHP INSIDE -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper_">
    <table border="1" style="font-size:10pt;" class="wrapper">
        <tr><th></th><th>受注番号</th><th>会社名</th><th>受注日</th><th>販売会社</th><th>契約年数</th><th>月額利用料</th></tr>
        <tbody>
            < SOME PHP INSIDE ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

> 

```
.wrapper {   /*  table */
  height:40%; 
  width:60%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper_ { /* remove div */
  display: block;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto
}
```

Comment: no problem, note that wrapper will always be put at otter layer, so the content's width inside get to overflow